# How to tell UIImagePickerController what's the maximum camera resolution for a photo?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I only need small thumbnail images for contacts, but the camera returns HUGE images with all the megapixels. So my app ends up with memory warnings every time the user takes a photo. That's bad.

Is there a way to tell the UIImagePickerController what the maximum image size is, so it won't waste all that memory upfront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't set the quality of images on UIImagePickerController.

If you use AVFoundation and an [AVCaptureStillImageOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can set the quality. This involves considerably more work though since you'll need to build the preview and everything yourself.

As long as you make a thumbnail from the big image and don't keep it around, you don't need to worry too much about memory used by UIImagePickerController.